# Regex problem - missing matches

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here's a short regex example:

```
preg_match_all('~(\s+|/)(\d{2})?\s*–\s*(\d{2})?$~u', 'i love regex  00– /   03–08', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The regex only matches '03–08', but my intention was matching '00–' as well. What is the problem? Anyone could explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion at the end:

```
-\s*(\d{2})?$~u
```

Means that you can only have spaces and/or optionally two digits between your match and the end of the string.  This means `00-` can't match since there's other stuff between it and the end of the string.

If you remove the `$`, it should work as you intend.

Comment: Where did that $ come from????? Thank you, Adam. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. That $ was sitting there and I simply didn't notice it!